# PDO: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, parameters, pdo

I have come across this warning I've not seen before:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters in...

Referring to the following PDO query (have simplified the function for ease of reading):

```
$offset = 0;
$limit = 12;
function retrieve_search_posts($searchfield, $offset, $limit){


        $where = array();

        $words = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$searchfield);

        array_unshift($words, '');
        unset($words[0]);

        $where_string = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0,count($words), "`post_title` LIKE ?"));

        $query = "
                                SELECT  p.post_id, post_year, post_desc, post_title, post_date, img_file_name, p.cat_id
                                FROM    mjbox_posts p
                                JOIN    mjbox_images i
                                ON      i.post_id = p.post_id
                                        AND i.cat_id = p.cat_id
                                        AND i.img_is_thumb = 1
                                        AND post_active = 1
                                WHERE $where_string
                                ORDER BY post_date
                                LIMIT :offset, :limit
                                DESC";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        foreach($words AS $index => $word){
            $stmt->bindValue($index, "%".$word."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $searcharray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $searcharray;
    }
```

The function and PDO query works fine without the offset and limit variables included in the query. So what might be causing this warning?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be the fact that you're mixing named parameters (`:offset`, `:limit`) with positional parameters (`LIKE ?`) as the warning states?

Comment: @MarcB Maybe I am missing something, but where do you see an sql injection hole?

Comment: @Wiseguy thanks, I know what their called now too :p

Comment: @Marc B How have I done this?

Comment: the hole is here "WHERE $where_string."  $where_string is devised from $searchfield, which I am assuming the user passes in.  You should be using a bindParam for this.

Comment: @CountMurphy If you check how that string is built, you'll see it comes from an array containing just `post_title LIKE ?` strings

Comment: @jeron, looks like you're right.  dont know how I missed that. I really shouldn't only skim the code before commenting...

Comment: As jeroen says, I assumed it is okay because I bind the parameter that is used in the `$where_string` variable that is in the query!?

Comment: @crm: you build your own imploded `$where_string`, then embed it directly in to the sql. you're NOT using bound parameters there. it's direct sql injection. even if the original stuff going into $where_string isn't coming from (say) $_POST, you can STILL inject yourself. **ANY** data going into an sql query can be used for injection, unless you use proper escaping, or placeholders/prepared statements.

Comment: @MarcB The OP is building `$where_string` concatenating hard-coded `post_title LIKE ?` strings with `OR` strings and then binding his variables to the placeholders. Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change

```
LIMIT :offset, :limit
```

to

```
LIMIT ?, ?
```

and

```
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

to:

```
$stmt->bindValue($index+1, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue($index+2, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 13):

in your where_string you use `?` that is a positional parameter and in your limit and offset you use `:` that is a named parameter that is causing the warning don't mix them

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I could use a named parameter in the where_String instead of the positional one or vice versa?

Comment: @crm Either replace the `?` instances with named parameters like `:pattern1`, `:pattern2`, or the named parameters with `?`, and they'll have indexes of count+1 and count+2, where count is the number of patterns being checked.