# UPDATE with IN using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am migrating an old system to PDO for security reasons.
Now I'm having a hard time making an UPDATE with filtering with IN.The filter in the WHERE is working but the UPDATE vestments id_user and date_prog are not.

Currently I don't get any error message and when I print the stmt I get:

```
UPDATE os SET id_user =?, date_prog =? WHERE words IN (?,?)
```

The Array ():

```
Array ([1] => 30762507, [2] => 30762508)
```

Even so, UPDATE does not happen. Where can I go wrong.

So far I've used an old question as a basis:
[PDO: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888198/pdo-invalid-parameter-number-mixed-named-and-positional-parameters)

Thanks in advance for any help.
Hug.

My complete code:

```
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
$date_prog = $_POST['date_prog'];
$list_words = $_POST['words'];


$where = array();

$words = preg_split('/[\s]+/',$list_words);

array_unshift($words, '');
unset($words[0]);
        
$IN  = str_repeat('?,',count($words) - 1) . '?';
    
$stmt = "UPDATE os SET id_user = ?, date_prog = ? WHERE words IN ($IN)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);

foreach($words AS $index => $word){
    $sqlupos->bindValue($index, $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$stmt->bindValue($index+1, $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue($index+2, $date_prog, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$data_stmt = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: It should be `... where number in ...`, not `where in number...`

Comment: It was just a typo in the example.

Comment: It was just a typo in the example. As I reported the problem is to filter the data using the IN and when doing this in UPDATE.

Comment: In this case either the parameters do not match any records or the update will not change any of the fields.

Comment: Please look this solution: https://phpize.online/?phpses=a412e4c8fa64a1b9e9d35c59733bf436&sqlses=eb53699a14e52c37aa37dff42c04166c&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP the PDO method [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) uses named placeholders, so you can use next code:

```
$IN = ':a' . implode(', :a', array_keys($words));

$sql = "UPDATE os SET id_user = :id_user, date_prog = :date_prog WHERE words IN ($IN)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach($words AS $index => $word){
    $stmt->bindValue("a$index", $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt->bindValue(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':date_prog', $date_prog, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Look live code on [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=a412e4c8fa64a1b9e9d35c59733bf436&sqlses=eb53699a14e52c37aa37dff42c04166c&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)